# Angular Custom Validation of Nested Attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have an Angular-based form for which I want to apply specific validation:

```
<form name="createProject" novalidate>
<span ng-show="createProject.projectName.$invalid">Please enter a name for the project.</span></br>
<input type="text" ng-model="newProject.project.name" name="projectName" placeholder="Project Name" required>

<div ng-repeat="topic in newProject.project.topics_attributes">
    <span>Topic {{$index + 1}}</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="topic.name" placeholder="Topic Name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="topic.feed_size">

    <div ng-repeat="topic_source in topic.topic_sources_attributes">
        <span>Topic {{$parent.$index + 1}} Source {{$index + 1}}</span>
        <select ng-model="topic_source.platform" ng-options="platform for platform in platforms" topic-source-required parent="$parent.topic.name">
            <option value="">-- platform --</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" ng-model="topic_source.keywords" placeholder="Topic Keywords" topic-source-required parent="$parent.topic.name">
        <button ng-show="$last" ng-click="addTopicSource($parent.topic)">Add Topic Source</button>
    </div>
</div>

<button ng-click="addTopic()">New Topic</button>
<input type="submit" ng-click="addProject()" ng-class="{ disabled: createProject.$invalid }" ng-disabled="createProject.$invalid" value="Add Project">
</form>

<a href="#">Back</a>
```

In the form, a project can have either zero or multiple topics. Each topic must have at least one topic source. Basically, I want to create validation that checks if a topic is being added (added being defined as having a name) and if so require that it has at least one topic_source with platform and keyword fields entered associated with it.

Is this even possible? I'm not very familiar with Angular custom validation so I'm not sure how to begin implementing something like this.

****Edit****

Current progress on custom validation directive:

```
angular.module('dashboard').directive 'topicSourceRequired', ($parse) ->
  require: "ngModel"
  link: (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) ->
    topicName = $parse attrs.parent
    scope.$watch topicName, (topicName) ->
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift checkForExistence if topicName

    checkForExistence = (topicSource) ->
        if topicSource
          ctrl.$setValidity "topicSourceRequired", true
        else
          ctrl.$setValidity "topicSourceRequired", false
        topicSource
```

Ok, getting closer for this validation. Right now the validation seems to be checking if the two topic_source fields have values independent of whether or not the parent's name field has a value, AND the topic_source fields only register as invalid if a field has been entered and then erased.

How do I make sure the checkForExistence function is only called when topicName has a non empty string value? Second, how do I make sure blank fields are invalid without having to modify them somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom directive that requires ngModel which gives you access to the ngModelController (look at the require option when creating a directive).

Basically, you can listen for changes to the value by registering with the $viewChangeListeners, read the current value from $viewValue, and set the validation through the controller function

```
$setValidity(validationErrorKey, isValid);
```

The validationErrorKey you set is the a boolean value on the $erros object of the controller.

Take a look at this page in the docs to get you going:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you saying to bind the validation to the model and then check to make sure the model is formatted correctly?  How does it know where to attribute the error in the DOM to?

Comment: Sorry for not being completely clear. All I'm saying is you need to understand how forms and their contained inputs work in order to do custom validation. AngularJS is brilliant at letting you do this, but as with everything takes time to learn. The link I posted above perhaps isn't the best place to start - try here instead: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to get how it works. I've built a directive using $watch to detect if a change has been made to the $parent scope (the topic) and check if the topic_source fields have values. The problem is $watch only seems to check when fields are initially added and the function to check values never seems to get run. I'm not quite sure how to get $watch to check for any change to the model and how to get it to call the check values function.

Comment: Try using $watchCollection.

Comment: Nope, neither work. Docs suggest $watch and $watchCollection get called if there's a call to $digest(). I thought changing the value of a model attribute would call $digest() but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: $digest() is called on an interval, unless you're writing tests you don't really need to worry about that.